# What is the standard for naming variables and why?

Tags: objective-c

I'm going through some training on objective-c.  The trainer suggests setting single character parameter names.  The .NET developer in me is crying.  Is this truly the convention?  Why?

For example,

```
@interface Square : NSObject
{
  int size;
}

-(void)setSize: (int)s;
```

I've seen developers using underscores `int _size` to declar variables (I think people call the variable declared in `@interface` ivar for some unknown reason).  Personally, I prefer to use descriptive names. E.G.

```
@interface Square : NSObject
{
  int Size;
}

-(void)setSize: (int)size;
```

C, like C# is case sensitive.  So why don't we use the same convention as .NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many standards for variable naming, it depends on the programming language used, and on the core developers involved in the project.

In case of objective-c, I think this page should answer your question:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html

As per using single-letter parameter names as a general rule, it is clearly a horrible idea, don't listen to it.

Comment: Especially with good autocompletion.  Self-documenting code ftw!

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood correctly you are talking about [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

In this case you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) for an explanation.

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822487/how-does-an-underscore-in-front-of-a-variable-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-class-work) for the second part of your question.

Comment: Yes and no.  To me, Hungarian Notation implies appending type information to variable names, which is not what I am suggesting at all.  I simply mean to say variable names should be descriptive. Regarding underscores, the underscores make sense for private variables.  Still, I prefer using casing over appending underscores.  This avoids breaking intellisense-like features which sort alphabetically.

Comment: what do you mean with "descriptive"? appending type names is also descriptive but is wrong, in general creating this bind between labels and descriptions leads to a lot of useless noise in the communication, also remember that this kind of work ( naming ) should be "atomic", as short as possible and with all the meaning in a single word. Something like Tyre.getPressure(), it's abstract enough and you get all the info that you need, it's abstract because you are not binding the concept of the Tyre with a Car or a Bus, *continues*

Comment: writing CarTyre.getPressure() is wrong because you are not taking advantages of the OO design and you can simply have a class Tyre that inherits from the class Car. If you read the post that i have linked  you will find that this behaviour can only generate noise and is just useless and wrong.

Comment: Using single letters for parameters/variables is not Hungarian notation.

Comment: @user827992, I'm sorry, but Tire inherits from Car?  In what world do you live where a "Tire is a kind of Car"?  Because that's what inheritance implies.  Also, this is indeed not Hungarian Notation at all.